# How do I get a file from a one-off process in Kubernetes?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a test process which produces a file as an output.

I want to start this test process during a build, run it to completion, then collect the file that it produces and copy it back into the build context.

What is the correct way to do this in Kubernetes/Helm?

The build process has access to `kubectl` and `helm` CLI tools.

I have a requirement not to use `kubectl exec`, because the cluster settings do not allow it.

**Some details:**

I was able to configure a one-off process using a `Pod`.

I set up the process to store the output file in a volume mount, which is mounted to an `emptyDir` volume.

I cannot figure out how to get the output file.

I tried `kubectl cp`, but I can't get it to work (no such file or directory).

I can't figure out how to inspect the contents of a stopped container.

I can't figure out how to see what's in the volume.

`kubectl logs` shows that the test process ran successfully. The file is generated within the container and stored at the expected location.

**Quick update:**

In my local minikube environment, I was able to set up a persistent volume and copy the output file back to the host file system. I will try it next in Jenkins environment.

Here is the output from `kubectl cp` on my local (boot2docker) environment:

```
$ kubectl cp my-pod:/home/node/output . -c mycontainer
error: home/node/output no such file or directory
```

`/home/node/output` is the volumeMount path within the container.

Comment: Can you please post the command that you are using for kubectl cp ?

Comment: Also, mounting a volume will help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Updated question with the latest.

Comment: Is there a way to fetch a file directly from a bound persistent volume?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a requirement not to use kubectl exec, because the cluster settings do not allow it.

Without the `kubectl exec` command, I can suggest to do it that way:

1. Run your test as a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) inside a cluster.
2. Use shared volume like NFS or SMB to store your file.
3. Get files from the shared volume, which you can mount to your build system.

Also, many build systems have an Artifacts storage, and it can be the best option to store test results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand how to do step 3. That's the whole source of my problem. I am using Jenkins declarative pipeline.

Comment: For NFS shares, you will need an NFS server (it can be any Linux system, check that [article](https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-setup-nfs-server-in-linux/)), then you can mount shared volume to your agents (check the same article) and to your [pods](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs).

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try.